# php -f file.php cats file to command line?

Tags: php, command-line, command-line-interface

I've just written a simple php file only containing:

```
echo 'some text';
```

I now want to execute that from the command line. When I do `php -v`, I get:

```
HP 5.5.12-1~dotdeb.1 (cli) (built: May  6 2014 03:56:10)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans
```

but when I do `php -f file.php`, it simply cats the file:

```
# php -f file.php
echo 'some text';
#
```

I also tried `php file.php`, but to no avail.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? All tips are welcome!

Comment: you're probably being downvoted because you didn't include the contents of `file.php` so it's not a proper question...

Answer (score 3):

Juste add opening & closing tags `<?php ... ?>` into file.php and it will work.